Reference request: $\mathrm{Sym}^2_0(T^*M) \simeq \Lambda_- \otimes \Lambda_+$

I am looking for proof of the ''well-known'' result that for a $4$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$, we have an isomorphism
$$
\mathrm{Sym}^2_0(T^*M) \simeq \Lambda_- \otimes \Lambda_+
$$
between the traceless, symmetric, covariant $2$-tensors on $M$ and the tensor product of the spaces of anti-self-dual and self-dual $2$-forms on $M$.

I saw in some papers on Einstein manifolds that the isomorphism is the map
$$
\Lambda_- \otimes \Lambda_+ \ni \omega_- \otimes \omega_+ \mapsto \omega_- \omega_+  \in \mathrm{Sym}^2_0(T^*M),
$$
where $\omega_- \omega_+$ is given, in coordinates, as
$$
(\omega_- \omega_+)_{ij} = (\omega_-)_{ik} g^{kl} (\omega_+)_{lj}.
$$
However, none of these references provide a proof of this result. While I understand the definition of $\omega_- \omega_+$, I do not know how to prove that it is the desired isomorphism; I am not sure how to even check that $\omega_- \omega_+$ is a symmetric tensor.
Edit. I also posted this question on MathOverflow here.

That notation customarily denotes the symmetric tensor product: $\omega\eta = \frac12(\omega\otimes\eta+\eta\otimes\omega)$.

@TedShifrin That is the notation used in, for instance, "Wormholes in ACH Einstein manifolds". I did see other papers writing it as $\omega_- \circ \omega_+$.

Right. The latter is a bit more modern.

The question has received an answer on MathOverflow here. One indeed should symmetrize the isomorphism I gave before.
